# Ajax Response Laravel to object

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I created an ajax request to display results from my table eloquent query who depends one a select box "poule".

Everything is working but when I run the ajax request by selecting a poule_id from the select box I need to display the json result. I would like to display the result as my foreach loop in the table ($equipes as $equipe) because as you can see I display value from models in relation.

UPDATED:

My model Equipe:

```
class Equipe extends Model
{

    public function structure()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Structure');
    }
```

My model CompetEquipe (i use it to display my foreach)

```
class CompetEquipe extends Model
{
    public function equipe(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Equipe' , 'equipe_id');

    }
```

> Like this i can access to the tables in relations in my foreach

```
<tr>
        <td>
            <a href="{!! route('club.show', $equipe->equipe->structure->id) !!}">{{$equipe->equipe->structure->nom_structure}}</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="{!! route('equipe.show', $equipe->equipe->id) !!}">{{$equipe->equipe->lb_equipe}}</a>
        </td>
        <td>{!! Form::text('nb_bonus') !!}</td>
    </tr>
```

Actually with this way I can only display equipe_id but I would like to display the object to access to the other models in relation and display the result as my foreach in the table like:

```
@foreach($equipes as $equipe)
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="{!! route('club.show', $equipe->equipe->structure->id) !!}">{{$equipe->equipe->structure->nom_structure}}</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="{!! route('equipe.show', $equipe->equipe->id) !!}">{{$equipe->equipe->lb_equipe}}</a>
        </td>
        <td>{!! Form::text('nb_bonus') !!}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Hope someone understood what I want to do. thanks a lot in advance friends

> here my JSON RESULT : {"equipes":[{"equipe_id":1,"poule_id":1}]}

My select filter search:

```
<select id="poule">
  @foreach($select_poules as $select_poule)
      <option value="{{$select_poule->id}}">{{$select_poule->lb_poule}}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

My table:

```
<table id="equipes" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Club</th>
            <th>Nom de l'équipe</th>
            <th>Bonus(+/-)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($equipes as $equipe)
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="{!! route('club.show', $equipe->equipe->structure->id) !!}">{{$equipe->equipe->structure->nom_structure}}</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="{!! route('equipe.show', $equipe->equipe->id) !!}">{{$equipe->equipe->lb_equipe}}</a>
            </td>
            <td>{!! Form::text('nb_bonus') !!}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My controller:

```
public function searchEquipes(Request $request)
    {
        $equipes = [];

        if($request->has('poule_id')){
            $equipes = EquipePoule::where('poule_id',$request->poule_id)
                ->get();
        }


        return response()->json(['equipes' => $equipes]);
    }
```

My script:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('change', '#poule', function() {

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            url : '/licences/public/search/equipes',
            data : {
                poule_id : $('#poule').val()
            },
            success:function(data){

                $('#equipes').empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.equipes.length; i++) {
                    $('#equipes').append('<tr><td>'+data.equipes[i].equipe_id+'</td></‌​tr>')
                }
            },
            timeout:10000
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What does your json look like? Could you add it to the question please

Comment: of course ! i updated the post now

Comment: i also added my controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace the content of your table with the response of an AJAX request you jQuery's [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/).
You need to change your jQuery success function slightly.

```
success: function(data) {
            //Build the row data as you wish to display it
            var rowData = ""
            $.each(team["equipes"][0], function(i, value) {
                var rowData +=  $("#equipes").append("<td>"+value+"</td>");
                 })
            $("#equipes").replaceWith("<tr>"+rowData+"</tr>

            $("#equipes").append("</tr>");
          }
```

This will replace your initial table data with that of your select.

Comment: No no i would like to display the same results as the foreach at the same place with the same values like <a href="{!! route('club.show', $equipe->equipe->structure->id) !!}">{{$equipe->equipe->structure->nom_structure}}</a>

Comment: i want that my foreach result change results with the selected poule_id but with displaying the same values at the same area (in my foreach) is it possible ?

Comment: Ok, I see. You will have to output more information in your json. $equipe->equipe->structure->nom_structure and $equipe->equipe->lb_equipe are values you will need to pass down through your json if you wish to display them with jquery.  You will have to add these values to the json response of your controller.

Comment: Ok i see ! do you know how i could pass the values in my controller to JSON ? I need to make a foreach loop ($equipes as $equipe) in the controller and get the values ?

Comment: sorry , i'm not a pro of ajax , jquery and json

Comment: That's quite alright, I assume from your code 'structure' and 'equipe' are relationships you have defined. Could you include them in the question, and the values they will return.

Comment: i updated in the top of the post , this is what you was looking for ?

Comment: Yes there needs to be a relation for the structure. You certainly have all of the pieces to do what you need. You would query for the structure(/name) that the team has. And add the as as item you output in your json response. I have altered my answer in response to you wanting to replace your initial table data

Comment: What's the relation between EquipePoule and Equipe?